# How to use a custom mysql docker image with test data for local development

Tags: mysql, docker

Before I keep going down this path (explained below) can someone verify I am on the right track? Or How do you work with test data for local development and refresh it regularly.

For our local development we run a standalone mysql and use an import script to load sanitized test data. The import script takes over 2 hours. I am at the point where I have mysql running in a container and I can load the test data inside. The container fully loaded is 50GB. I am having trouble saving it with `docker commit` and `docker export/docker import`. "Error processing tar file(exit status 1): unexpected EOF"  From researching this error I need to be on the latest version of Docker 18.09.3. Right now I am using an AWS ami that only goes to version 18.06.1-ce. So currently I am spinning up another EC2 server with a Centos ami to load the newest version on docker.

I have been working on this project for 2 weeks and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Using volumes wouldn't help?

Answer (score 0):

If container size if 50GB, I assume you are loading full mysql data in the docker image or load data in container and now want to same container state.
Best way would be to mount `host` directory to container to hold `mysql` data. In this way, your mysql image is immutable and data is mounted on the image. 
This data can be copied on any other server and run the new mysql container.